# Logstash extracting values from sp_executesql

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

We're tracking and shipping our SQL Server procedure timeouts into Elasticsearch, so we can visualize them in Kibana in order to spot issues.

Some of our SQL queries are parameterized and use `sp_executesql`.

Would it be possible to extract its parameters and their values from query?

For instance:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'EXEC dbo.MySearchProcedure @UserId=@p0,@SearchPhrase=@p1'
    , N'@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(max)'
    , @p0 = 11111
    , @p1 = N'denmark';
```

And get this result out of it:

```
{
  "Procedure": "dbo.MySearchProcedure",
  "Statement": "exec sp_executesql N'exec Search.GetAnalysisResultsListTextSearch @SubscriberId=@p0,@SearchTerms=@p1,@SortType=@p2',N'@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(max) ,@p2 int',@p0=47594,@p1=N'denmark',@p2=0",
  "Parameters": {
    "UserId": 11111,
    "SearchPhrase": "denmark"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for the ruby{} filter.  First, locate all your key=value pair in the query (@userid=@p0, probably using ruby's [scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) feature), then locate the assignments (@p0=1234, using scan again), then create a new field combining the two (userid=1234).  In the ruby filter:

```
 event['userid'] = '1234'
```

Comment: I thought about this. Looks like there's nothing easier. Thank you.